# The default case is already defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, jquery-ui, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to revise an old WebLogic project in Eclipse, the project has some reference to jquery lib. One strange error I get in the `jquery.combo.select.js` file is "the default case is already defined". I am sure this must be some configuration issue, but I could not figure it out?

[image: default case is already defined error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same issue,I've solved it using following steps

1. went to Project Properties > JavaScript > Include Path > Source, there is "Excluded" to highlight and press "Edit" button, here you are able to add what you want to exclude (file, folder, pattern).
2. I excluded "test.js" file
3. pressed apply...

Answer (score 2):

Exclude javascript from source